# How to collect from Internet, Postal Codes of Cities and States? (WEB SCRAPPING SSIS)

Tags: excel, csv, web-scraping, ssis, postal-code

In an SSIS project, I need to merge my Cities with Postal codes.
I tried to scrap datas from Internet but there are many errors like special characters that are not readable or makes errors,warnings  in ssis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you will want to buy a product to clean and standardize your address data. Many exist and I've dealt with a number of them over my career but ultimately, they derive their power from the USPS master list of addresses.

There are plenty of places on the internet where you can get a list of the approximately 43k zip codes. However, here's your first problem

Let's say you have these two businesses in your spreadsheet

- 9012 Blue Ash Rd, Blue Ash, OH
- 9856 Montgomery Rd, Cincinnati, OH

Blue Ash is zip code 45242 and Cincinnati is also 45242 (and a host of other zip codes) so the first problem is that multiple cities can share the same zip code.

Along those lines, ZipCode 42602 is Eubank KY. It's also Static, Seventy Six, Snow, Seminary, Highway, Aaron and Browns Crossroads.

Next up, Springfield, MO. Or more appropriately

- SPFD, MO
- SPGFD, MO
- SPNGFLD, MO
- SPRNGFLD, MO
- SPGFLD, MO
- Springfield, MO
- Spring field, MO

Data is dirty when entered by dirty people. All of those cities are the same place but different approaches people take to abbreviate it. How do you expect to make a match there?

Pay for an API call from MelissaData/SmartyStreets/Google or Bing Maps/ and let the professionals deal with it.

If you insist on trying to brute force this, start with feeding your City & State into the USPS and consume the results https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?bycitystate I have no idea what the rate limiter might be there so be wary that you could get your IP banned, soft or hard, for too many calls in a period of time.